# How to check a file's existence in phone directory with phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, ajax, cordova

I'm writing an Android application with Phonegap 1.4.1 and Sencha that downloads and reads pdf files. How can I check whether the file exists in the phone directory using either phonegap methods, javascript or ajax?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could check if the file exists using the FileReader object from phonegap.
You could check the following:

```
var reader = new FileReader();
var fileSource = <here is your file path>

reader.onloadend = function(evt) {

    if(evt.target.result == null) {
       // If you receive a null value the file doesn't exists
    } else {
        // Otherwise the file exists
    }         
};

// We are going to check if the file exists
reader.readAsDataURL(fileSource);
```

Comment: this dosn't work for me(and don't know how can it work for any....The method readAsDataURL require a blob, not a string(path), as specified in [FileReader](http://www.javascripture.com/FileReader) doc

Comment: path to my file is this ///storage/emulated/0/MyMusic/abc.mp3. it says it must be blob. Please suggest how it will work.

Answer (score 32):

I had the same problem. I could not manage to get Darkaico's answer to work, but with the answer of Kurt I could make it work.

Here's my code:

```
function checkIfFileExists(path){
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSystem){
        fileSystem.root.getFile(path, { create: false }, fileExists, fileDoesNotExist);
    }, getFSFail); //of requestFileSystem
}
function fileExists(fileEntry){
    alert("File " + fileEntry.fullPath + " exists!");
}
function fileDoesNotExist(){
    alert("file does not exist");
}
function getFSFail(evt) {
    console.log(evt.target.error.code);
}
```

Then you only need to execute like this:

```
checkIfFileExists("path/to/my/file.txt");
```

Comment: As Marek says my function has an error that open the file. So your solution is better and clean.

Comment: Just to note that it's a bit difficult to use checkIfFileExists within the context of an algorithm (e.g. it can't return true/false because it's asynchronous), so I would suggest to pass the callbacks as parameters. Something like: checkIfFileExists(path, fileExists, fileDoesNotExist)

Comment: If using angular you can use the defer system:

function checkIfFileExists(path) {
            var def = $q.defer();
            window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function (fileSystem) {
                fileSystem.root.getFile(path, { create: false }, def.resolve(true), def.resolve(false));
            }, def.reject); //of requestFileSystem

            return def.promise;
        }

Comment: I passed ///storage/emulated/0/MyMusic/abc.mp3 as the path to my file but it says file does not exist. It is there though.

Answer (score 21):

I get a handle to the file using the `.getFile('fileName',{create:false},success,failure)` method. If I get the `success` callback the file is there, otherwise any failure implies that there is a problem with the file.

Answer (score 21):

The above answers did not work for me, but this did :

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(fullFilePath, success, fail);
```

from : http://www.raymondcamden.com/2014/07/01/Cordova-Sample-Check-for-a-file-and-download-if-it-isnt-there

Answer (score 4):

Darkaico, Kurt and thomas answers didn't work for me. Here's what worked for me.

```
$.ajax({
url:'file///sdcard/myfile.txt',
type:'HEAD',
error: function()
{
    //file not exists
alert('file does not exist');
},
success: function()
{
    //file exists
alert('the file is here');
}
});
```

Comment: Great, you save the day testing my cordova app on firefoxos device

Answer (score 2):

@PassKit is correct, in my case i needed to add an eventlistener

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
       window.requestFileSystem = window.requestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;
       window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, fsSuccess, fsError);
}
```

then for the value "fileSystemRoot" in the funtion "fsSuccess"

```
var fileSystemRoot; // Global variable to hold filesystem root

function fsSuccess(fileSystem) {
       fileSystemRoot = fileSystem.root.toURL();
}
```

the function "checkFileExists"

```
function checkFileExists(fileName) {
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.open('HEAD', fileName, false);
    http.send(null);
    if (http.status.toString() == "200") {
        return true;
    }
    return false
}
```

for check if the file exists

```
if (checkFileExists(fileSystemRoot + "fileName")) {
     // File Exists
} else {
     // File Does Not Exist
}
```

the var fileSystemRoot in IOS return me "cdvfile://localhost/persistent/" 
and the files was store in "//var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/{AppID}/Documents"

Many thanks to @PassKit, this run in synchronous mode and was tested in IOS 8.1

Comment: this gives me: XMLHttpRequest cannot load file://..... Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, app, https

Comment: also with .replace('file://','') works, but always returns true

Answer (score 1):

Kurt and Thomas gave better answers, because Darkaico's function not only checks if the file exists but also opens the file and reads it until the end.

This isn't a problem with small files, but if you check a large file then the app may crash.

Anyway, please use .getFile method - it's the best option.

Comment: You need to be mindful that the `.getFile` method is asynchronous - your result variable will only be set when the file system callback has returned.  If your code tries to immediately access the result variable, it may not yet have been set.

Answer (score 1):

I've tested the following code snippet, and works quite well for me in PhoneGap 3.1

```
String.prototype.fileExists = function() {
filename = this.trim();

var response = jQuery.ajax({
    url: filename,
    type: 'HEAD',
    async: false
}).status;  

return (response != "200") ? false : true;}

if (yourFileFullPath.fileExists())
{}
```

Comment: It is returning 200 even if file doesnt exist

Answer (score 0):

The trouble with all of the current answers is that they depend on an asynchronous callback which updates a global variable.  If you are checking multiple files, there is a risk that the variable will have been set by a different callback.

A basic Javascript XMLHttpRequest check is perfect for synchronously checking the file is accessible to via Javascript.

```
function checkFileExists(fileName){

    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.open('HEAD', fileName, false);
    http.send(null);
    return (http.status != 404);
}
```

Just pass in the full path to the file and then you can reliably use:

```
if (checkFileExists(fullPathToFile)) {
    // File Exists
} else {
    // File Does Not Exist
}
```

To store the root path in a variable you can use:

```
var fileSystemRoot; // Global variable to hold filesystem root

window.requestFileSystem  = window.requestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, fsSuccess, fsError);

function fsError() {
    console.log("Failed to get Filesystem");
}

function fsSuccess(fileSystem) {
    console.log("Got Filesystem: Root path " + fileSystem.root);

    // save the file to global variable for later access
    window.fileSystemRoot = fileSystem.root;
}
```

Comment: @AshishNautiyal Thanks for the down vote - perhaps you would be kind enough to elaborate on why.

Answer (score 0):

note:

when I get the filesystem I save it in a var under a macro pg object:

```
pg = {fs:{}}    // I have a "GOTFS" function... a "fail" function
pg.fs.filesystem = window.requestFileSystem(window.PERSISTENT, 0, pg.fs.GOTFS, pg.fs.fail);
```

so my code is pretty simple...

```
var fileExists = function(path, existsCallback, dontExistsCallback){
    pg.fs.fileSystem.root.getFile(path, { create: false }, existsCallback, dontExistsCallback);
        // "existsCallback" will get fileEntry as first param
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This code can be used for custom cases, full documentation here: [download if not exist](https://www.raymondcamden.com/2014/07/01/Cordova-Sample-Check-for-a-file-and-download-if-it-isnt-there)

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", init, false);

//The directory to store data
var store;

//Used for status updates
var $status;

//URL of our asset
var assetURL = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cfjedimaster/Cordova-Examples/master/readme.md";

//File name of our important data file we didn't ship with the app
var fileName = "mydatafile.txt";

function init() {

$status = document.querySelector("#status");

$status.innerHTML = "Checking for data file.";

store = cordova.file.dataDirectory;

//Check for the file.
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(store + fileName, appStart, downloadAsset);

}

function downloadAsset() {
var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
console.log("About to start transfer");
fileTransfer.download(assetURL, store + fileName,
function(entry) {
console.log("Success!");
appStart();
},
function(err) {
console.log("Error");
console.dir(err);
});
}

//I'm only called when the file exists or has been downloaded.
function appStart() {
$status.innerHTML = "App ready!";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    var fileexist;
function checkIfFileExists(path){
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSystem){
        fileSystem.root.getFile(path, { create: false }, fileExists, fileDoesNotExist);
    }, getFSFail); //of requestFileSystem
}
function fileExists(fileEntry){
    alert("File " + fileEntry.fullPath + " exists!");
    fileexist = true;
}
function fileDoesNotExist(){
    alert("file does not exist");
   fileexist = false;
}
function getFSFail(evt) {
    console.log(evt.target.error.code);
    fileexist=false;
}
```

now you can use conditions

```
if(fileexist=="true"){
//do something;
}
else if(fileexist=="false"){
//do something else
}
```

Comment: The trouble with this solution is that it the callbacks are asynchronous.  You cannot guarantee that the global variable fileexist will accurately reflect the file's existence, particularly when checking multiple files in quick succession.

Comment: Yeah than have to change strategy . But you feel happy on Down voting :P:P

Comment: I've posted a synchronous solution.  Down voting and commenting the reason for the down vote alerts users to potential issues with a solution.

Answer (score -3):

If you need a boolean-compatible method...

```
function checkIfFileExists(path){
    var result = false;

    window.requestFileSystem(
        LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 
        0, 
        function(fileSystem){
            fileSystem.root.getFile(
                path, 
                { create: false }, 
                function(){ result = true; }, // file exists
                function(){ result = false; } // file does not exist
            );
        },
        getFSFail
    ); //of requestFileSystem

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Your result variable will be out of scope when set from the anonymous callback function.  It will also not be set before the function returns and therefore this solution will always return false.

Answer (score -3):

I took @Thomas Soti answer above and trimmed it down to a simple yes/no response.

```
function fileExists(fileName) {
  window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSystem){
      fileSystem.root.getFile(cordova.file.dataDirectory + fileName, { create: false }, function(){return true}, function(){return false});
  }, function(){return false}); //of requestFileSystem
}
// called as
if (fileExists("blah.json")) {
or
var fe = fileExists("blah.json) ;
```

Correction....this does NOT work.  I am working on the fix now.