# How to check if directory and file exists in Phonegap framework?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, blackberry

How to check if directory and file exists in Phonegap framework?
How is this done in Phonegap
**Please help me**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10294166/how-to-check-a-files-existence-in-phone-directory-with-phonegap

Comment: Hello @amrit_neo this good answer but if i want also check for directory so hows its possible ?

Comment: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_file_file.md.html#DirectoryEntry    check for getDirectory() method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the File reader object.

```
var reader = new FileReader();
var fileSource = <here is your file path>

reader.onloadend = function(evt) {

if(evt.target.result == null) {
   // If you receive a null value the file doesn't exists
} else {
    // Otherwise the file exists
}         
};

// We are going to check if the file exists
reader.readAsDataURL(fileSource);
```

Comment: Hi @Hasintha this is for file checking and what about the directory ??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10294166/how-to-check-a-files-existence-in-phone-directory-with-phonegap