# Checking if a file exists

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to see if a local file exists when a link is clicked, but it always says it doesn't exist. Can anyone spot a glaring mistake i've made?

Thanks

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   jQuery("a").click(function(){

   var href = jQuery(this).attr('href');

   jQuery.ajax({
       url:href,
       type:'HEAD',
       error: function() {
          alert(href);
       },
       success: function() {
           alert('Huzzah!');
       }
   });
});
```

Comment: [SOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) violation? Security feature: No website is allowed to access random files on my disc?

Comment: Massive potential, they're all static html files. Could it be this? Is there an alternative?

Comment: did you use webserver?

Comment: 'fraid not. It's a phone gap application

Comment: done. I think that is the problem. Ajax is used to send request to some server, if you dont use webserver, then ...

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to access a file on your local file system, this is probably blocked by your browser because of Same Origin Policy.

One simple way to get around this is to run a local HTTP server.

e.g. if you have python installed, just run

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

Comment: It's a phonegap application

Answer (score 2):

Ajax can not be performed with file:// protocol. Since you are using Phonegap, there is built in object to used  to check if file exist or not: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.3.0/phonegap_file_file.md.html#FileReader

[How to check a file's existence in phone directory with phonegap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10294166/how-to-check-a-files-existence-in-phone-directory-with-phonegap)

```
var reader = new FileReader();
var fileSource = <here is your file path>

    reader.onloadend = function(evt) {

        if(evt.target.result == null) {
           // If you receive a null value the file doesn't exists
        } else {
            // Otherwise the file exists
        }         
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(fileSource);
```

good luck !!