# how to check file is exist or not in mobile sd card using javascript

Tags: javascript, cordova, filereader, android-sdcard, filewriter

How do I check if an Excel file (.xlsx) exists on the SD card on Android using PhoneGap? If the file exits, how do I then import and export the file contents through javascript?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check a file's existence in phone directory with phonegap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10294166/how-to-check-a-files-existence-in-phone-directory-with-phonegap)

Answer (score 0):

First add the cordova [File](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#File) Plugin into your project.Then use the following code :

```
    var reader = new FileReader();
    var fileSource = <file path>;

    reader.onloadend = function(evt) {

        if(evt.target.result != null) {
            // If you receive not null value the file exists
        } else {
            // Otherwise the file doesn't exists
        }         
    };

    // We are going to check if the file exists
    reader.readAsDataURL(fileSource);
```