# How to make function with forEach loop check 2 files, if exists return with string if not return file name

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap, file-manager, local-files

I have application can download and save file in LocalFileSystem and i need run 2 file in same time , before start i need to check if those file exist or not .
i made somthing like this but i thing its stupid function ,it works with console but dosent work as return string

```
function fileExist(songName,vocalName){ // i change it a bit for this example
  var downloadedFolder =  'filesystem:http://192.168.1.20:3000/persistent/downloaded/';
  var fileName = [];
  storedFiles = [];
  misingFiles = [];
  fileName[0] = ({'value':'Song','name':musicName}); 
  fileName[1] = ({'value':'Vocal','name':vocalName});
  fileName.forEach(function(item) {
    let path = downloadedFolder + item.name;
    const fName = item.value;
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(path, 
    function(){
        storedFiles.push( fName )
        if ( misingFiles.length == 0 && storedFiles.length == 2) {
            return 'All';
        }
    },
    function(){
        misingFiles.push( fName )
        if ( misingFiles.length == 2 ){
            return 'Nothing';
        }
        else if ( misingFiles.length == 1 && storedFiles.length == 1){
            return misingFiles[0];
        }
    })
})}
```

i want this function to use it somthing like this :

```
if ( fileExist(songName,vocalName) == 'Nothing' )
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're using NodeJS, you can use [fs](https://npmjs.org/fs) to check if a file exists or not.

```
if (!fs.existsSync(path)) {
    // file doens't exists
} else {
    // file does exists
}
```

If you're not using NodeJS you can setup a simple localhost server and send a request to that to check if it does exists with fs.

If you're using electron (idk which framework you're using) you can use  [the Electron ipc](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-main) to send messages from the main process to the renderer process.

Comment: sry i didnt mention its phonegap mobile app , i think i cant use NodeJS on mobile

Answer (score 0):

You could check if the file exists using the [FileReader object from phonegap](https://www.javascripture.com/FileReader). You could check the following:

```
var reader = new FileReader();
var fileSource = <here is your file path>

reader.onloadend = function(evt) {

    if(evt.target.result == null) {
       // If you receive a null value the file doesn't exists
    } else {
        // Otherwise the file exists
    }         
};

// We are going to check if the file exists
reader.readAsDataURL(fileSource);
```

If that one does work check the comments of this post:
[How to check a file's existence in phone directory with phonegap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10294166/how-to-check-a-files-existence-in-phone-directory-with-phonegap) (This is were I got this answer from)

Comment: i know how to check files but i dont know how to make function for checking 2 file in same time and return result as string .